# Capturing parameters of a method at runtime in Java

Tags: java, aspectj

Our application uses several back-end services and we maintain wrappers which contain the methods to make the actual service calls. If any exception occurs in any of those methods while invoking a service, we throw a custom exception encapsulating the original exception as shown below.

```
interface IServiceA {
 public void submit(String user, String attributes);
}

public class ServiceAWrapper implements IserviceA {
 private ActualService getActualService() {
  .....
 }

 public void submit(String user, String attributes) {
  try {
   Request request = new Request();
   request.setUser(user);
   request.setAttributes(attributes);
   getActualService().call(request);
  } catch(ServiceException1 e) {
   throw new MyException(e, reason1);
  } catch(ServiceException2 e) {
   throw new MyException(e, reason2);
  }
 }
}
```

I would like to know if there's any framework that would allow me to

1. capture (and probably log) all the
   parameters passed to my wrapper
   methods at run-time; if the methods
   are called.
2. capture the actual exception
   object(MyException instance in above
   example), if any thrown; so that I
   could append the passed parameters
   to the object at run-time.

I am currently exploring AspectJ to see if it can address my requirements, but I am not sure if it can be used to capture the parameters passed to methods at runtime and also to capture exception objects, if any occur.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the replies. I am currently using 'JoinPoint' to capture the parameters. However, I see that the 'getArgs()' method in 'JoinPoint' just returns me the values of the parameters and not their names. How can I retrieve the names of the parameters too ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With AspectJ, you can [use `around` advice](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/quick-advice.html) to execute advice instead of the code at the join point. You can then execute the actual join-point from within the advice by calling proceed. This would allow you to capture the input parameters, log them, and proceed to call the actual method.

Within the same advice you could capture any logs throw from the method, and inspect or log them before passing it back up to higher levels.

Answer (score 3):

Matt B's answer is right. Specifically, you can do something like this:

```
aspect MonitorServiceCalls {

  private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLog("ServiceCallLog");

  Object around() throws MyException: call(public * *(..) throws MyException) 
                                      && target(IServiceA+) {
    MethodSignature msig = (MethodSignature)thisJoinPoint;
    String fullMethName = msig.getMethod().toString();
    try {
      Object result = proceed();
      LOG.info("Successful call to {} with arguments {}", 
               fullMethName,
               thisJoinPoint.getArgs());
      return result;
    } catch(MyException e) {
      LOG.warn("MyException thrown from {}: {}", msig.getMethod(), e);
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AspectJ is the right option.  You will be able to get hold of the parameters by way of a JoinPoint object that will be passed to your advise methods.  You can also get hold of the exception either by implementing an after throwing advise or an around advise.